# importing js module in JS script

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn, resemblejs

How to import resemblejs module in my JS script ?

My script contains a function like -

```
    function compareImages(picture1,picture2)
    {
         var diff =resemble(picture1).compareTo(picture2).ignoreColors().onComplete(function(data)
          {
               //console.log(data);  
          });
    return data;
   }
```

the 'return data' is so I can invoke this function in my java program using scriptengine and display the 'data' ( see console.log(data) in code above) in java console.

```
    Object res = inv.invokeFunction("compareImages", <path of image1>, <path 
                                  of image2>);
    System.out.println(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nashorn comes with its own `load( js )` method.
You can use it to import modules

Example:

> script1.js

```
function say(thing){
    print(thing);
}
```

> script2.js

```
load("./script1.js");
say("Hi");
```

This should print Hi

Comment: script1 and script2 have to be in the same folder ?

Comment: Yes they must be in the same folder, but you can also use absolute paths or urls

Comment: I have kept my JS file 'MainJS' in the same folder as resemblejs.. 
But getting this error 
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot load script from ./resemble.js in <eval>...

Comment: maybe it's a security error? or the resemble.js is not found?